# How to merge two table data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need all users data in one blade, I have `table1` and `table2`.

**table1**

```
'id','name','phone','email','status','created_at'
```

**table2**

```
'id','name','mobile','email','status','created_at'
```

I tried to do this but not an expected result.

```
 $usersTbl = DB::table('table1')->select('id','name','phone','email','status','created_at')->groupBy('phone')->paginate(20);

 $ordersTbl = DB::table('table2')->select('id','name','mobile','email','status','created_at')->groupBy('mobile')->paginate(20);

 $items=$ordersTbl->merge($usersTbl);
 dd($items);exit;
```

Comment: What's the end goal? are they going to be in 1 big array or are you looking for something else?

Comment: once you fetch the data from both tables you can merge the result instead of the merging table

Comment: maybe you need to use union, so you can merge using SQL query instead laravel/php

Comment: @AmitSharma can you give me example how to merge it

Comment: see in the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pagination, if you merge it the pagination need to recalculate.

You need to use **unionAll** and then paginate:

```php
$usersTbl = DB::table('table1')->select('id','name','phone','email','status','created_at')->groupBy('phone');

$ordersTbl = DB::table('table2')->select('id','name','mobile AS phone','email','status','created_at')->groupBy('phone');

$mergeTbl = $usersTbl->unionAll($ordersTbl);
DB::table(DB::raw("({$mergeTbl->toSql()}) AS mg"))->mergeBindings($mergeTbl)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: `(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::unionAll does not exist.`

Comment: @WorldsHero Do you get them or use paginate in usersTbl?

Comment: use paginate in usersTbl

Comment: @WorldsHero don't use it. Follow my code, groupBy them and then unionAll them, and then paginate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204861/discussion-between-worlds-hero-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score -1):

Try This Method:

```
public function Details($id) {
    /** Make an empty array **/
        $patients = array();
    /** Get Data from first model **/
        $user_details = User::where(['id' => $id])->first();
    /** Get Data from second model **/
        $profile_details = Profile::where(['id' => $id])->first();
        $patients[] = $user_details; 
        $patients[] = $profile_details; 
        }
        return view('custom-view', compact('patients'));
    }
```